# Sum of squares of integers question

Tags: number-theory

Use congruence's to prove the following result.

If $n \cong 3 $ mod 4, then n cannot be written as the sum of the squares of two integers.

Im not even really sure where to start this a hint would be great.

Comment: If you only wish for a hint, consider the contrapositive statement.  Look at what happens for the sum of two squares where: 1) both are even, 2) one is even and the other odd, 3) both are odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

If $n=a^2+b^2$ try to find all possibilities for $a^2+b^2 \pmod{4}$